# Selecting the right licensing model

Tags: licensing, copyright, github, educational-resources

I'm trying to select the correct licensing model for training content I create and currently host on Github. The content may be migrated in the future to another hosting platform **or** be converted to a static website (Jekyll, VuePress, etc.) and obscured from the fact that its hosted on Github hosted.

**Issue:**

- The content I create contains a **mix** of code and tutorial text
- Because of the nature of the code (low-code solution), it is NOT separable from the tutorial text itself

**Simple content example:**

#### Create the screen component

- Click `Components` under `Tree View`
- Click `New component`
- Rename the component to `cmpRespScreen`
- Set `cmpRespScreen` properties:

  - Width: `Max(App.Width, If(App.Width < App.Height, App.DesignWidth, App.DesignHeight))`

    - Explanation: Set the component width to the larger of:
    - The device width OR,
    - When the device is in portrait orientation, the width in App Settings OR
    - The height in App Settings
    - Substitute "device" for "browser window" when the app is used on laptop

**Researched:**

I like the way the [Python Data Science Handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/) is licensed (CC-BY-NC-ND license for text, MIT for code). I'd like to mimic some of this, but again, I can't easily differentiate between code and text in my content.

I also reviewed [Choose a License](https://choosealicense.com/non-software/), but being new to the game AND having non-traditional content is making things tough.

Any ideas?

Comment: You tell us a lot about the separability issue but you don't tell us anything about what the licence you end up with must achieve.  What do you want to allow people to do with your content?

Comment: Eventually, I'd like to package things into a body of knowledge. The BOK would be a static website for people to use freely OR pay $X to have a hardcopy shipped to them. Again, very similar to the PDSH mentioned above.

Comment: Are you asking for a licence that lets people "*freely use*" your content on the site, but doesn't let them download a copy?

Comment: That sounds about right. There will be instructional content that explains concepts and definitions in my own unique way. The content will also be structured in a logical way that I put together. 
I don't want someone to copy the content word for word and make money off of it. Feels a bit unfair.

Comment: [Freedom 2](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) is the freedom to redistribute verbatim copies, so what you want is not a free licence within the meaning of this site.  Moreover, there is nothing wrong with [charging money](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html) for those copies.  I have therefore voted to close the question as off-topic.